# MS Exchange 2016: REST API - get calendar of another user

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

i need to get calendar of another person in simillar way i am getting my via

https://exchange/api/v2.0/Users('username@domain.com')/calendarview?StartDateTime=XY&EndDateTime=XY

the request for another person doesn't work

https://exchange/api/v2.0/Users('anotherUser@domain.com')/calendarview?StartDateTime=XY&EndDateTime=XY

results>> REST APIs for this mailbox are currently in preview etc..

I found out there's way in rest api v1.0 but didn't find same possibility in v 2.0.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs

Does exists way in api/v2.0 for this?

Thx

Comment: Do you have permissions to this other calendar? What is your accounts assigned roles on the server?

Comment: I am using the same account as for Outlook where i am able to see other's calendar. I don't see detail of meetings but a note "busy" and can also fetch fromDateTime toDateTime. Such an information is sufficient for me and I need to obtain via rest call.

Comment: Have you talked with your IT department about this?

Comment: Before I ask them I would like to ensure I am using the right API call in order to retrieve calendars data. If i am able to see in outlook calendar of others (not with details, only when they are busy which is sufficient) with my domain credential i would expect i would be able to retrieve same data via the API. But of It doesn't have to be like that. For the reason I am asking here.

Comment: also via my credential i am able to retrieve data via the call https://exchange/api/v2.0/Users('user@domain') about another user so i more suspect the query for the calendar isn't correct one but i was unable to find correct in documentation

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about corporate/enterprise IT and OP has an IT staffperson responsible for support of the systems they are using.